# Increasing virtual hard drive capacity in vbox

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, disk-space

I am using Virtual Box.

I have a virtual hard drive storage 8GB (dynamic allocated).

Later on, that drive is full. I don't know how to increase the capacity.

Therefore, I decide to add the second hard drive.

But the problem is not solved.
(low disc space message in my Ubuntu virtual machine)
(the second virtual hard drive probably does not been detected by my Ubuntu virtual machine)

Can anybody give me a suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to first [resize your Virtual Box disk image](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=resize+virtualbox+vdi), then launch your VM and [resize the parition](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=resize+partition+linux) on your VM. The 2nd VDI was probably recognized by the VM (and the guest OS) but merely having a 2nd hard drive in a machine does not automagically free up the disk space on offending drive, you would have to clean up the drive yourself (delete/move files).

Hope that can help.